# PA Server Monitor: SNMP Monitor can't run

Tags: monitoring, snmp

We are using PA Server Monitor and one of the machines (Linux) can't be monitored.

```
SNMP Monitor

Failed to query iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysUpTime ....
Failed to query iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifOperStatus.2

Can't Run
```

Does somebody know the the monitoring process is called on the Linux Machine so it can be restarted? The machine is using Fedora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Fedora should probably be running `snmpd`. Either

1. snmpd is not installed
2. snmpd is not running
3. it has a different SNMP community configured
4. firewall is blocking SNMP queries
5. snmpd has been configured to listen only 127.0.0.1 instead of your network interface(s)
6. something else, this one you need to figure out yourself

Comment: It was already running, but it stopped to run after some restarts ... But you have made a good list of possible causes. I only had to `/etc/init.d/snmpd restart` and everything works again. Thanks!